# phpmyadmin update query using 3 tables in giving error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I am getting the following Error

> 064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'from `catalog_product_flat_1` a inner join
>   `catalog_product_entity` c on a.sku' at line 3

when I try out the below query on phpmyadmin

```
update a 
set a.small_image = b.value
from `catalog_product_flat_1` a
inner join `catalog_product_entity` c
on a.sku = c.sku
inner join `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` b
on b.entity_id = c.entity_id
```

I also tryout without using alias but still same issue

Answer (score 1):

The `SET` clause comes *after* the `JOIN` clauses:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_flat_1` a
inner join `catalog_product_entity` c
on a.sku = c.sku
inner join `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` b
on b.entity_id = c.entity_id
SET a.small_image = b.value
```

See the documenation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html